# What is the proper way to cast a negative normalized floating point 32-bit number to a signed byte

Tags: c, casting

I want to cast a normalized 32-bit floating point (in the range -1.0f to 1.0f) to a signed byte in the range (-128 to 127). I don't care about the massive precision loss because I am just trying to save memory.

How would I cast the range -1.0f to 1.0f into -128 to 127 (float -> int8_t)?

Edit: if possible it would be nice to preserve 0 as 0 after the conversion

Comment: Forget programming. Can you write a math formula for mapping `[-1, 1]` range into `[-128, 127]` ?

Comment: @ikegami i haven't thought about that yet. I think it would be good to preserve 0 as 0. But I would think that would up the difficulty of the problem significantly

Comment: Well, it would still be zero, but there would be more negative inputs that map to zero than positive ones. Anyway, the just-posted answer addresses the issue, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @ikegami makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `127` to `-127` is sufficient, it really is this simple:

```
int8_t value = INT8_MAX * floatVal;
```

That will give you a range of `+/-INT8_MAX`, or `127` to `-127`.  That is a linear mapping that has the advantage of `0.0f` mapping to the integral value of `0`.

You can get more complex, with non-linear mappings and/or an offset to get the full range of `INT8_MIN` to `INT8_MAX`, but given you just "need a general ballpark number", it's probably not worth the code complexity.

Comment: It's not quite linear because you used truncation instead of rounding. (Twice as many inputs map to 0 as any other number, and only a single input maps to each of -127 and +127.)

Comment: Some rounding might be applied instead of just truncating. Otherwise +/-127 will be far less likely than other numbers.

Comment: Do you know of resources of where I can read up on the nonlinear mappings to get the full range? of INT8_MIN to INT8_MAX